# Rails - shovelling into an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, activerecord

I have a model, a DynamicPage, that can have a featured_child_dynamic_page as follows:

```
has_many :dynamic_page_featured_relations
has_many :child_featured_dynamic_pages, through: :dynamic_page_featured_relations, source: :dynamic_page
```

In my controller I'm trying to do the following, where both parent_page and featured_child_page are saved dynamic pages. :

```
parent_page.child_featured_dynamic_pages << child_featured_page
```

After I run this operation in console, it returns the child_featured_page. However when I run parent_page.child_featured_dynamic_pages it returns an empty association. I have also tried:

```
parent_page.child_featured_dynamic_page_ids << child_featured_page.id
```

Once more this returns the ID, however when I check the array of ID's it is empty. Any advice is appreciated

Comment: Have you tried `parent_page.save!` after passing the featured page to the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save parent_page after the assignment:

```
parent_page.save
```

This persists the object with its new child objects to the database, creating the necessary association records.